# PostgreSQL division by zero when ordering

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, divide-by-zero

i need to execute this query in postgres but i couldn't get rid of this error

```
    ERROR: division by zero
SQL state: 22012
```

here is the query :

```
select id,rates_sum,rates_count from tbl_node  order by rates_sum/rates_count DESC;
```

i know i can add a small value to the `rates_count` but i get inaccurate values .

Is there a way to make the postgres ignore this error ,or using if statement to check zeros and replace them with any number.
and again the error in the order by clause.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    rates_sum,
    rates_count 
FROM 
    tbl_node  
ORDER BY 
    rates_sum / NULLIF(rates_count,0) DESC NULLS FIRST;
```

You could also use `NULLS LAST`, if you want to.

Comment: Thanks Man :), I will never forget this

Comment: you could also use NULLIF instead of CASE to make it shorter (see http://sqlbrain.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/avoid-sql-divide-by-zero-errors-by-using-nullif/)

Answer (score 0):

how about a `where rates_count != 0`?

Comment: i need to return all the nodes ,event if it has rates_count ==0

Comment: You can union it with another query with a `where rates_count == 0` and another ordering.

Comment: can you please give me an example :),i tried but i get errors

Comment: i cant put the order by in the first select ,and putting it for both will give me the same problem