# Ordering by average rating - how to speed it up?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sql-order-by, postgresql-9.3

I have two columns in a table:

```
rating_total integer
rating_count integer
```

rating_total is a sum of total rates, and rating count is a number of total rating. I want to order by average rate:

```
ORDER BY (rating_total/rating_count) DESC, id ASC
```

Should I create separate column for `average_rate`? Or it is possible to create some index to speed this up?

---

I've managed to create index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX "posts-avg-rating-index" 
ON "Posts" (("rating_total"::float/(CASE "rating_count" WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE "rating_count" END)) DESC NULLS LAST, id DESC);'
```

Which works for ordering like this:

```
ORDER BY (("rating_total"::float/(CASE "rating_count" WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE "rating_count" END)) DESC NULLS LAST, id DESC)
```

Comment: Why not just `avg(rating)` (assuming you have a rating column)?

Comment: you should use separate `column` or take a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4068083/2749470) on this answer

Comment: @JackManey I am not performing any grouping, each row has already calculated rating_total & rating_count.

Comment: @BhargavModi so it is not possible to set up index for such query?

Comment: @user606521 take look on my previous edited comment

Comment: Did you try to create an index on `(  (rating_total/rating_count), id )`? You should also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info  and add the missing information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Will such index work with `rating_total / (CASE rating_count WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE rating_count END) DESC NULLS LAST, id ASC`?

Comment: most likely no, you probably should use same expression at index definition as you have in order by clause then it will work for sure.

Comment: there is not much you can do here apart from materializing the query or parts of it. you cannot create an index on the order clause as it is a dynamically generated value.

Comment: Well, it seems to be working for me (see edit) - I can see "Index Scan" in EXPLAIN ANALYZE when using proper ordering.

Comment: You should really avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hmm, most of my column names are camel-cased so they have to be quoted. Do you suggest to use underscored column names instead? To be honest I am using postgres for fetching data returned by REST API in JSON format, where camel-casing attributes in objects is a common convention.

Comment: Column names in PostgreSQL should always be lowercased with underscores used as word/token separators. Anything else is just asking for pain. And just because your data source is JSON from a REST API, that doesn't mean that the column names in your database have to follow the same naming conventions as the keys in the JSON responses.

Comment: As almost always, a table definition (`\d tbl` in psql) would have clarified a lot to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question created some confusion, since an "average rating" would normally be a value calculated across *multiple rows*, which cannot be indexed.

In your case you obviously want to order by the quotient of two columns in the *same rows*, which happen to be a "total" and a "count". For this case you can have an [expression index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html), of course - you found one yourself already.

You can simplify with [`NULLIF`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF):

```
CREATE INDEX posts_avg_rating_index
ON "Posts" (cast(rating_total AS float)/NULLIF(rating_count, 0) DESC NULLS LAST, id DESC);
```

Use the same expression in your query.

About `cast()` shorthand syntax `name::type` and expression indexes:

- [Postgres using an index for one table but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552825/postgres-using-an-index-for-one-table-but-not-another/28555617#28555617)

And rather use legal names. A dash (`-`) in identifiers is legal while double-quoted, but just asking for trouble.

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use a expression index over a materialized view and index or a [trigger updated] computed value column? It seems like the expression index would need to store the result internally anyway..

Comment: @user2864740: It's a good question. Both solutions have their own costs, benefits and side effects. Please ask a new *question* for this. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this question for context.